# The provided starting key does not match the range key predicate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDB table where:

```
PK: String
```

and a GSI on this table where PK and SK are attributes of the original table:

```
PK: String

SK: String
```

(actually the `SK` it's the `String` representation of a `Java Instant`)

For a test, I'm trying to crawl over the pages returned by the queryPage method.
I've created 4 items and set the page size to 2.

When retrieving the first page (2 items) I'm doing:

```
DynamoDbAddress key = new DynamoDbAddress();
key.setProvider(DATA_PROVIDER);

return dbMapper.queryPage(DynamoDbAddress.class, new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoDbAddress>()
                .withLimit(pageSize)
                .withIndexName(TABLE_GSI)
                .withHashKeyValues(key)
                .withRangeKeyCondition("Time", new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LE)
                        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(Instant.now().minus(26, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toString())))
                )
        .getResults();
```

This snippet is working fine and retrieves 2 elements as expected.
When retrieving the second page (the final 2 items), I'm doing:

```
    DynamoDbAddress key = new DynamoDbAddress();
    key.setProvider(DATA_PROVIDER);

    return dbMapper.queryPage(DynamoDbAddress.class, new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoDbAddress>()
            .withLimit(pageSize)
            .withIndexName(TABLE_GSI)
            .withHashKeyValues(key)
            .withRangeKeyCondition("Time", new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LE)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(Instant.now().minus(26, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toString())))
            .withExclusiveStartKey(Map.of(
                            "Provider", new AttributeValue().withS(lastProcessed.getProvider().toString()),
                            "Time", new AttributeValue().withS(lastProcessed.getTime().toString()),
                            "PK", new AttributeValue().withS(lastProcessed.getPartitionKey()))))
.getResults();
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
The provided starting key does not match the range key predicate
```

My interpretation of the error is that "the `lastProcessed` element does not match the condition expressed in the range key". However, this looks a little absurd to me, as it was retrieved by the very same query in the snippet executed a second before.

I've also verified the test data match the key condition

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to manually reconstruct the `ExclusiveStartKey`? To avoid issues, like the one you are seeing, you should call [`getLastEvaluatedKey()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/QueryResultPage.html#getLastEvaluatedKey--)

```
    DynamoDbAddress key = new DynamoDbAddress();
    key.setProvider(DATA_PROVIDER);

    return dbMapper.queryPage(DynamoDbAddress.class, new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoDbAddress>()
            .withLimit(pageSize)
            .withIndexName(TABLE_GSI)
            .withHashKeyValues(key)
            .withRangeKeyCondition("Time", new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LE)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(Instant.now().minus(26, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toString())))
            .withExclusiveStartKey(lastResult.getEvaluatedKey())
.getResults();
```

Comment: yeah, my problem here is that we're using a custom library to perform the crawling and I don't have access to the queryResultPage computed at the previous step

Comment: You should check the value you compute matches the expected value, the exception you receives indicates it does not.